# Please solve the error with the following codes

Tags: php

Shown below is the form for leave details (extracted from a table) of user where in after user checks the corresponding checkboxes the values get inserted into a table (code below this one)

```
<?php
session_start();
//$myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
if(!session_is_registered('myusername')){
//if(!session_register())

header("location:login_form.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Leave add form</title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="2" cellspacing="10pt" cellpadding="5pt">
<form method="post" action="leave_form_exec.php" >
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db_connect_eadmin.php');
$qry = "select per_no, office, leave_typ, pre_fr, pre_to, leave_fr, leave_to, days, lev_rsn, lev_add, sl_no, leave_typ, can_no, appliedon, post, pmt_per_no, pmt_name from tbl_golevapp, pis_mstr_table where post='N' and tbl_golevapp.per_no=pis_mstr_table.pmt_per_no";
print('<center> <table border="2" rules="all" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="110">');
?><tr><th width=10%>Personnel no of Officer</th><th width=30%>NAME OF THE OFFICER</th><th width=30%> OFFICE</th> <th width=15%>LEAVE TYPE</th><th width=10%>LTC IN THIS PERIOD</th><th width=10%>LEAVE FROM</th><th width=10%>LEAVE TO</th><th width=10%>DAYS</th><th width=10%>LEAVE REASON</th><th width=100%>LEAVE ADDRESS</th><th width=100%>APPLICATION DATE</th><th width=20%>ENTER SANCTION DATE</th><th width=20%>SELECT THE CHECKBOX</th> </tr>
<?php
$recset=odbc_exec($congpass,$qry);
if (!$recset) {exit("Error in SQL"); }
while(odbc_fetch_row($recset))
{
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php 
        $row['per_no']=odbc_result($recset,1);
        $row['office']=odbc_result($recset,2);
        $row['leave_typ']=odbc_result($recset,3);
        $row['pre_fr']=odbc_result($recset,4);
        $row['per_to']=odbc_result($recset,5);
        $row['leave_fr']=odbc_result($recset,6);
        $row['leave_to']=odbc_result($recset,7);
        $row['days']=odbc_result($recset,8);
        $row['lev_rsn']=odbc_result($recset,9);
        $row['lev_add']=odbc_result($recset,10);
        $row['sl_no']=odbc_result($recset,11);
        $row['leave_typ']=odbc_result($recset,12);
        $row['can_no']=odbc_result($recset,13);
        $row['appliedon']=odbc_result($recset,14);
        $row['post']=odbc_result($recset,15);
        $row['name']=odbc_result($recset,17);
                   echo $row['per_no']; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['office'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['leave_typ'];?></td>
         <td> <!--<input type="radio" name="ltc[]" value="yes" /> <strong>YES</strong>
            <input type="radio" name="ltc[]" value="no" /> <strong>NO</strong>--></td> 
        <td> <?php echo $row['leave_fr'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['leave_to'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['days'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['lev_rsn'];?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row['lev_add'];?></td>
        <!--<td> <?php echo $row['leave_typ'];?></td>-->
        <td> <?php echo $row['appliedon'];?></td>
        <!-- HIDDEN INPUT KD STYLE :)-->
        <input type="hidden" name="per_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['per_no']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="leave_typ[]" value="<?php echo $row['leave_typ']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="appliedon[]" value="<?php echo $row['appliedon']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="leave_fr[]" value="<?php echo $row['leave_fr']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="office[]" value="<?php echo $row['office']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="leave_to[]" value="<?php echo $row['leave_to']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sl_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['sl_no']; ?>"><br />
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sanction_date" > Enter Sanction Date in DDMMYYYY <br /></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="days[]" value="<?php echo $row['days']; ?>">
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['sl_no']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php //$i=$i+1;?>
  <?php
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
?>
<br />
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="save" id="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
 <!-- FORM CLOSE -->
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

values are then inserted through the following code

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login_form.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Leave form execute</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db_connect_eadmin.php');
$qry_form="select max(transact_no) from leave_transactions";
$recset=odbc_exec($congpass,$qry_form);
if (!$recset) {exit("Error in SQL"); }
while(odbc_fetch_row($recset))
{
$transact=odbc_result($recset,1);
}
$counter = count($_POST["name"]); /* COUNT THE PASSED ON NAME */
echo $counter;// Echo for check
//echo $_POST["name"];

  for($x=0; $x<=$counter; $x++){
    echo $_POST["name"][$x]; // Echo for check
    if(!empty($_POST["name"][$x]))
    {
        echo $_POST["name"][$x];// Echo for check
       $transact=$transact+1;
      $p_no = $_POST['per_no'][$x];
      echo $p_no;// Echo for check
      $s_no = $_POST['sl_no'][$x];
    //  $ = $_POST['piaddress'][$x];
      if(($_POST['appliedon'][$x])<($_POST['leave_fr'][$x]))
      {
      $nbtd='NORMAL';
      }
      else
      {
      $nbtd='BKDTD';
      }
      $leave_typ = $_POST['leave_typ'][$x];
      if(($_POST['days'][$x])==0.5)
      {
      $hdcl='Y';
      }
      else
      {
      $hdcl='N';
      }
      $office=$_POST['office'][$x];
      $appliedon=$_POST['appliedon'][$x];
      $lv_fr=$_POST['leave_fr'][$x];
      $lv_to=$_POST['leave_to'][$x];
      $sanc_date=$_POST['sanction_date'];
      $ltc=$_POST['ltc'];
      $days=$_POST['days'][$x];
      $qry="INSERT INTO leave_transactions(transact_no,  
      personnel_no, 
      section_code,
      normal_or_bkdtd,  
      leave_type,      
      half_day_cl,
      half_day_ind,
      application_date,
      from_date,      
      to_date,       
      sanction_date,
      mc_code ,
      sanct_auth,
      leave_days )
      VALUES 
('$transact','$p_no','$office','$nbtd','$leave_typ','$hdcl',NULL,'$appliedon','$lv_fr','$lv_to',
      '$sanc_date',0,'GENERAL MANAGER/OITC','$days')";
                            echo $qry;
      $recset=odbc_exec($congpass,$qry);
      if(!$recset) 
      {
        die("ERROR !!!!! QUERY NOT INSERTED");
      }
      $qr1="update tbl_golevapp set post='Y' where sl_no='$s_no' && per_no='$p_no' && post='N'";
      $recset1=odbc_exec($congpass,$qr1);
      echo "<strong> VALUES SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED </strong>";
    } /* END OF CHECKING THE CHECKBOX IF SELECTED */
  } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

?>
</body>
</html>
```

but instead only the first row values as echoed in the preceding code are inserted (with an error since in `$qr1="update tbl_golevapp set post='Y' where sl_no='$s_no' && per_no='$p_no' && post='N'";`) .... and on insert it is picking only the first row as displayed

Answer (score 0):

`&&` are not supported in sql query. You need to replace it with `AND`.

Try changing:

```
$qr1="update tbl_golevapp set post='Y' where sl_no='$s_no' && per_no='$p_no' && post='N'";
```

to

```
$qr1="update tbl_golevapp set post='Y' where sl_no='$s_no' and per_no='$p_no' and post='N'";
```

Comment: Error with the query was corrected but still it is not picking the data corresponding to the query when the checkbox is selected.... Instead it is inserting the data corresponding to the result from the first row of the query